# Using icacls to set correct permissions for all app_data folders on drive

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I'm in the process of setting up a new server from a backup of a load of different websites. Copying across the backup has lost all the permissions for each file/folder, so I need to set the correct permissions. I know I can use `icacls` to do this manually, but I figured it'd be quicker if I was able to run a script that finds all the `app_data` folders on the new drive and recursively sets the file permissions for `IIS_IUSRS`.

I'm not sure where to start on this. Can anyone help? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options that come to mind:

1. Robocopy's /Copy Parameter which has an `s` option for security.
2. NTFSSecurity Module, obviously conceptually similar to icalcs. For obvious reasons this is my first choice for dealing with NTFS security.
3. `Get/Set-Acl`.  Anything beyond the most basic work usually had me resorting to .Net classes. Don't get me wrong, PowerShell's great at that, but for something as central to Windows as NTFS ACLs I always expected something more native. Ergo the NTFSSecurity Module.  That said, in this case, where you simply want to copy an ACL it may be as simple as something like below:

```
$ACLModel = Get-Acl -Path <SourceFolder>
Set-Acl -Path <DestFolder> -AclObject $ACLModel
```

Comment: Thanks. Option 1 is unfortunately not possible at this stage as the files have already been copied across to the new server (it'd take me a week to redo it!)

I think I understand option 3, but I'm not sure how to apply this to only folders matching `app_data` without having to do it manually. Is there a simple way to find all the folders with that name and then loop through them with this solution?

Comment: I figured out that I could get the list I required using the following: `(Get-ChildItem -Path W:\ -Include "app_data","temp","tiles" -Recurse -Directory).Fullname | Set-Content C:\files.txt`. So was then able to loop through each line in the resulting file and apply the permissions. There's probably a simpler was to do it though.